# Lightning Component :: Account Hierarchy

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I created a lightning component that is wrapping a component I downloaded from the appexchange and passing the recordId to it.  However, what I add to my page no recordId is passed and the section is blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >
<kkltng:AccountHierarchy accountId="{!v.recordId}" noOfParents="10" /> </aura:component>
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the accounthierarchy component, is this account hierachy you are referring: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A000000rMXGUA2, if so it is a managed package to start with how did you manage to see the attributes? 2) I even tried extending this component(without even looking at the attributes!!) and it throws  ":cannot extend non-extensible component "

Comment: Hello Abby, did you get this working? I think you were trying to embed the Hierarchy component provided by Salesforce Labs, whose code is unfortunately not open source yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the attribute of the recordId for using it;

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
```

Comment: did you get this working? I was trying basically the same stuff as the OP, and was passing "recordId" attribute, but it doesn't allow me to save the component stating "Internal Error" and an ErrorId to contact support with.

Comment: @sfdcdev27 please post a question with relevant code so we can try to help

Comment: Thanks Itai, I was able to solve my problem. Issue was on my end (had a domain name but didn't deploy that to users) so my installed Salesforce Labs managed lightning component wasn't coming from Lightning App Builder. hence was trying to embed the installed component into my own component which is rather unnecessary.